# Need JOLT spec for array input JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, object

I am working on transforming a complex json using JOLT.

Input JSON:

```
    { "data":
     [ 
      { 
       "fieldname": "Name", 
       "fieldvalue": [ "John Doe" ] 
    },
     { "fieldname": "Title", 
    "fieldvalue": [ "Manager" ] 
    }, 
    { "fieldname": "Company", 
    "fieldvalue": [ "Walmart" ] 
    }
    ] }
```

Expected Output:

```
    { 
    "finalPayload":{ 
    "PI":{ 
    "EmpName":"John Doe", 
    "EmpRole":"Manager" 
    }, 
    "Company":"Walmart"
     } 
    }
```

I am unable to understand how to access and assign "fieldvalue" in output based on "fieldname". Please help me with the JOLT spec.

Note: The order of name, title and company in input JSON will be jumbled and random meaning its not mandatory that under "data" array first object will be related to "Name" only.

Answer (score 1):

Hi hope this helps you in resolving your issue.
You can have condition in Jolt too, by going inside the variable and checking the fieldname.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "fieldname": {
            "Name": {
              "@(2,fieldvalue)": "finalPayload.PI.EmpName"
            },
            "Title": {
              "@(2,fieldvalue)": "finalPayload.PI.EmpRole"
            },
            "Company": {
              "@(2,fieldvalue)": "finalPayload.Company"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "finalPayload": {
        "PI": {
          "EmpName": "ONE",
          "EmpRole": "ONE"
        },
        "Company": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

May I introduce an alternative library to solve the issue.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
implementation 'com.octomix.josson:josson:1.3.21'

-------------------------------------------------

Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{\"data\":[{\"fieldname\":\"Name\",\"fieldvalue\":[\"JohnDoe\"]},{\"fieldname\":\"Title\",\"fieldvalue\":[\"Manager\"]},{\"fieldname\":\"Company\",\"fieldvalue\":[\"Walmart\"]}]}");

JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "map(" +
    "  finalPayload: map(" +
    "    PI: map(" +
    "      EmpName: data[fieldname='Name'].fieldvalue[0]," +
    "      EmpRole: data[fieldname='Title'].fieldvalue[0]" +
    "    )," +
    "    Company: data[fieldname='Company'].fieldvalue[0]" +
    "  )" +
    ")");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "finalPayload" : {
    "PI" : {
      "EmpName" : "JohnDoe",
      "EmpRole" : "Manager"
    },
    "Company" : "Walmart"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but we cant use alternate lib